# LINQ query using an array containing search values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is basically a question of how do I get an array of values from a table where the table key matches an array of search values.

If I have array internalCustomers[]:

```
1001
1003
```

and then I have a table modeled by the entity framework called WinFlexCustomer:

```
Customer, TaxID
1000, "CBA"
1001, "RCS"
1002, "Weekly ACH"
1003, "Daily ACH"
```

How can I design a LINQ query to return an array containing the TaxID values matching the internalCustomers array? I'm hoping the indices of each array will match so I can process each and have them in sync.

I was thinking something like this could work, but I'm getting syntax errors.

```
var query = from c
            in context.WinflexCustomers
            where c.InternalClientNum.Contains(customer.ToList())
            select c.TaxID2
```

Comment: I'm new to LINQ so I have been exploring how to build the query by what I've seen in a few free online how to videos. I can retrieve the entire column of TaxID values and I can retrieve one based on a search value. I do not yet know how to build the syntax for using the internalCustomers[] array as search critera.

Comment: Then throw up some code to show us where you started, and where you went wrong - we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than processing the arrays side-by-side and relying on their indexes being in sync, just allow the database to return the ID along with the name:

```
var customerIds = new[]{1001, 1003};
var query = 
        from c in context.WinflexCustomers
        where customerIds.Contains(c.InternalClientNum)
        select new { c.InternalClientNum, c.TaxID2 }
foreach(var customer in query)
{
    var clientNumber = customer.InternalClientNum;
    var taxId = c.TaxID2;
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following runtime error on that code: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @CodenameCain: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: I guess my target framework is set to 3.5 and System.Data.Entity is then 2.0.50727. This is just in a test console application. I should be able to change the target, but I'm not sure why it defaulted to 3.5.

Comment: It'll help to get up to date. If you can't, there are workarounds, but EF6 will definitely support converting that Contains expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an equivalent to T-SQL's `IN` syntax, if I understand you correctly:

```
var ret = db.WinFlexCustomer
            .Where(c => !internalCustomers.Contains(c.Customer))
            .Select(c => c.TaxID)
            .ToArray();
```

That maps more or less to:

```
SELECT TaxID
FROM WinFlexCustomer
WHERE Customer IN (1001, 1003)
```

I'm not completely sure what you're saying about "hoping the indices of each array will match so I can process each and have them in sync," since databases are inherently unordered (or at least, we're meant to treat them that way) but the indexes shouldn't matter if you do it this way.

**Edit:**

This is probably a better way to do what you want:

```
var ret = db.WinFlexCustomer
            .Where(c => !internalCustomers.Contains(c.Customer))
            .ToArray();
```

You'd then be able to evaluate each item to find its `TaxID` *and* its `Customer`, so you wouldn't have to map it against the other array via indexes.

Comment: Here I mean that if I process a for loop I can then be certain that internalCustomers[i] matches to taxIdArray[i]

Comment: @CodenameCain you aren't *really* going to get something like that out of a database, particularly not in an efficient way. You'd be better off to `JOIN` the results together then iterate through the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` rather than using a `for` loop.

Comment: @CodenameCain looking again, you probably don't even want to bother with joining since your main array has elementary types as elements. Just return both properties in your query, then loop through that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @CodenameCain are you guaranteed that every input will return a single match? If only one of your TaxIds is found, you'll have a hole in your array. That's a bit more complicated than a simple LINQ query.